# Page with on logged in User posts and info in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, author

I want to create a page where i can just show the Loggedin users post and info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by first using [`get_currentuserinfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) to get the user id, and then pass this to [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). With [the `author` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Author_Parameters) you get only posts from this author.